# How to initialize the array-like member variable in the constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

How to initialize the array-like member variable?

The `visual studio code` says:

> no matching function for call to 'Node::Node()' gcc line 12 col 9

```cpp
const int N = 100;

struct Node {
    int val, ch[2];
    /**
    void init(int _val) {
        this->val = _val, this->ch[0] = this->ch[1] = 0;
    }*/
    Node (int _val): val(_val) {
        this->ch[0] = this->ch[1] = 0;
    }
} tree[N];    // <--------- this is line 12


int main() {
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    tree[0] = Node(a);
}
```

Comment: The error is complaining about `tree[N]`, not `ch[2]`.  Like the error says, you need to give your class a default constructor.  If you don't want to do that, you need to specify an initializer for each array element.

Comment: Or simply use a `std::vector` with `push_back`/`emplace_back` instead of an array, which doesn't require you to immediately (default-)construct all elements.

Comment: Could you please give a code demo?

Comment: Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to *"search and then research"* and you'll find plenty of related SO posts for this.

Comment: And if your introductory book doesn't explain how to write default constructors, get a [better one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/212858)

Comment: why do you call it "array-like" ? It is an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **problem** is that when you wrote `tree[N]` you're creating an array whose elements will be **default constructed** but since there is no default constructor for your class `Node`, we get the mentioned error.

Also, `Node` doesn't have a default constructor because you've provided a converting constructor `Node::Node(int)` so that the compiler will not automatically synthesize the default ctor `Note::Node()`.

---

To **solve** this you can add a default ctor `Node::Node()` for your class.